# TinyMCE Nested Custom Formats

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm trying to create a series of inline text patterns to mark up TinyMCE (4.3.2) editor content with `<span>`s. I'm able to create my new custom format and register a new text pattern just fine, but the problem enters when trying to match nested patterns.

The TinyMCE init code for these custom formats is:

```
formats: {
    'innerFormat': {
        inline: 'span',
        classes: 'inner',
        exact: true,
        selector: 'span.inner'
    },
    'outerFormat': {
        inline: 'span',
        classes: 'outer',
        exact: true,
        selector: 'span.outer'
    }
},
textpattern_patterns: [
    {start: '{{', end: '}}', format: 'innerFormat'},
    {start: '[[', end: ']]', format: 'outerFormat'}
]
```

I want to be able to type this line in the editor:

```
[[outerText({{innerText}})]]
```

and receive this markup:

```
<span class="outer">outerText(<span class="inner">innerText</span>)</span>
```

but TinyMCE won't recognize the outerFormat ("[[ ]]") after it has matched the innerFormat ("{{ }}"), leaving me with:

```
[[outerText(<span class="inner">innerText</span>)]]
```

As far as I know, this is being caused by this block of code in the `textpattern/plugin.js` file: (~ line 101)

```
rng = selection.getRng(true);
container = rng.startContainer;
offset = rng.startOffset;
text = container.data;
delta = space ? 1 : 0;
```

The container returned from rng.startContainer changes from the parent `<p>` to a `text` container immediately after the inner format is matched.

How would I modify the TinyMCE textpattern plugin to search the parent block level element for a text pattern instead of the current selection's container?